# How to get a value from SubFactory Django Unit Test

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-unittest, factory-boy

I have three classes.In OrdFactory i wana pass only id to "sku" field and sku is integer field.

```
class CoFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Co

    name = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 'Co {}'.format(n))

class CrFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Cr

    name = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 'Cr {}'.format(n))

class OrdFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Ord

    sku = random.choice([factory.SubFactory(CrFactory), factory.SubFactory(CoFactory)])
    quantity = 75.6
```

I am getting following error.

int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Co'.

I have tried using id also:-

```
sku = random.choice([factory.SubFactory(CrFactory).id, factory.SubFactory(CoFactory).id])
```

but this also throwing error.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed using trait.Overload is also a alternative solution.
https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#factory.Trait

Comment: It is a cool and little known  feature